# Is x & 1 always a correct way to determine if a number is odd?

Tags: c++, bitwise-and

I've heard from many answers that `x & 1 == 1` will determine if a number is odd (which makes sense); but I never see this in practice (`x % 2 != 0` is usually used instead)

Are there any potential issues with using the bitwise and, or is `x % 2 != 0` just used because of other reasons (easier to understand, faster to compute, etc)?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that `x % 2 == 1` is "used because it is easier to understand" much less faster to compute, in fact, I don't even think it is as common to see it as `(x & 1) == 1`.  (Note that _without_ the parenthesis the bitwise-and expression [computes the wrong thing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence!)  It's probably a matter of personal preference.  Both are well accepted idioms.  I myself use the bitwise-and form exclusively.  (Not just because I _do_ find it easier to understand.)

Comment: Not until C++20 which requires integers to be stored in 2's Complement form.  Prior to C++20 I think this expression would be implementation defined.

Comment: Well, sure, 2's complement.  I can't count how many times in the several couple of decades I've been bit by _that_ issue...

Comment: @davidbak the proposal for 2's Complement contains a systems survey - I will see if I can find it.

Comment: `x % 2 == 1` is one form of the definition of an odd number, so it's the most obvious way to write the test. Bit manipulation **might** be faster, and probably was back in the olden days, but I wouldn't go that way unless the code was in a critical path and the generated code was, in fact, faster.

Comment: __p0907R1
Signed Integers are Two’s Complement__  [Survey of Signed Integer Representations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r1.html#survey)

Comment: [My attitude towards Unisys mainframes.](https://youtu.be/xLnTWxpTQt4?t=13)

Comment: The expression `x % 2 == 1` is not a general test for an odd number, because it will fail with negative odd numbers. Therefore, it should be `x % 2 != 0` to work with both negative and postitive numbers.

Comment: I usually see `x % 2 == 0` and `x % 2 != 0` (or their implicit-conversion equivalent, `x % 2`). I can't even remember seeing `x % 2 == 1`.

Comment: @davidbak `x & 1 == 1` does **not** compute "the wrong thing" without the parentheses. It computes *exactly* the same value, only by a somewhat unexpected path: `1 == 1` will evaluate to `true` (because it is true), then `x & true` will cause the `true` to integer-promote to `1`, after which `x & 1` remains, which *should* have been the whole expression from the start.

Comment: @EOF oh you are quite correct for this special case, thanks!

Comment: @EOF as far as "should have been the whole expression from the start" - you're right there too, but you'd be surprised (or maybe not) how many otherwise good programmers object to that in a code review .... no matter how much I push back ... (their objection is the "implicit" conversion to bool" "implicit" not in the C++ sense but in the "OMG this is confusing because you didn't write it out" sense).

Comment: @davidbak I understand this attitude - in a language like Rust that is explicitly designed to be explicit and "safe". In a language like c++, which is horrifically verbose for historical reasons, I'll take any safe-ish way to produce concise (and thus *readable*) code.

Comment: @RichardCritten If `x` is unsigned, then `x & 1` works in all versions of C and C++, because unsigned types are required to use base-2 representation. (Signed types pre C++20 did not have this requirement.)